# knowing salt that used when encryption AES 256

Tags: .net, encryption, rijndaelmanaged, initialization-vector

I have a password like *"`abd123456`"*, that I encrypt with AES-256 encryption. After Base-64 encoding, the result would be the 44 character string:

> IXCgaa5igYxzKTRTP+PMT7Bt9iIWiF6EWLmnKqZtlXI=

How can I know the salt that the .NET Framework's [RijndaelManaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) AES encryption class used during encryption?

I know the plaintext that is being encrypted, and the encryption key. But how do I know the [Salt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv(v=vs.110).aspx) used?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why this is new ideas that can help all to check his powerfull encryption  what is this site ( crypto ) ??

Comment: Nominating to reopen because of Artjom's edit.

Comment: no i have the normal password and pass after encryption i think it in AES 256 IN base64  how know the key that use ???

Answer (score 0):

You can read the salt from the [**`.IV`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the AES encryption object.

From MSDN documentation:

> The **IV** property is automatically set to a new random value whenever you create a new instance of one of the **SymmetricAlgorithm** classes.

Simply read the .IV after creating your encryptor. Then you can save the salt, or replace it with your own desired salt. Salt does not have to be secret, or even cryptographically random - it just has to be different each and every time.

Comment: ... The IV is not secret, so it can be sent along with the ciphertext. It's common to simply prepend it to the ciphertext, because its length is known in advance.

Comment: no i have the normal password and pass after encryption i think it in AES 256 IN base64  how know the key that use ???